# Is it thread-safe to call erase and push_back on std::deque from two threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, deque

Here're two functions:

```
std::deque<int> q;

// Push lots of elements to q
xxxxx

void foo() {
  auto begin = q.cbegin();
  auto end = q.cend();
  q.erase(begin, end);
}
void bar(int x) { q.push_back(x); }
```

Is is thread-safe to call `foo` and `bar` from two different threads? Is the behavior undefined?

Comment: No, it isn't thread safe, since neither of these operations is _atomic_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The execution of a program contains a **data race** if it contains two
>   conflicting actions in different threads, **at least one of which is not
>   atomic**, and neither happens before the other. Any such data race
>   results in undefined behavior.

Neither `erase` no `push_back` is atomic, so you will have a data race.

"Effective C++ Digital Collection" tells us that you all you can hope for from an implementation is:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not thread-safe to call `erase()` and `push_back()` on `std::deque<>` from two threads.

Comment: Comment instead of answering?

Comment: Even better, find the dupe ...

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not safe.

Neither `erase()` nor `push_back()` are *atomic* operations.

You need to synchronize access to the `std::deque` between the threads. The simplest solution would be a `std::mutex`.